# Angular JS $http.get does not receive data from PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I am using angular's $http.get function to call a PHP script file to retrieve data

```
var $promise = $http.get("../php-bin/example.php",obj).success(function(data) {

              console.log(data);
            });
```

The php is supposed to just get data from a mysql db to figure out a way to get data into my app

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$email = $user->email;
$pass = $user->pass;

$con = //a mysql_connection;
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}

$validateEmail = "SELECT `Email` FROM `newUsers` WHERE `Email` = '$email' ";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$validateEmail)) {
     if ($result->num_rows == 1){
        $date = '2014-08-13'; 
        //$sql = "INSERT INTO newUsers (Email, CreationDate, UserRef, Type, id) VALUES ('$email','$date','$email','Host','$ssid')";
        $sql = "SELECT `email` FROM `newUsers` WHERE `hashpass` = '$pass' ";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        return $row;
        //I never receive this data in the angular app.
    } 
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Could some one point me to the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you have a `return` statement instead of an `echo` statement. A `return` statement is not printed in the PHP output. [A `return` statement outside a function has only sense when you include the file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

```
$returned = include('the_file_you_showed_here.php');
//you will hold the row here
```

A `return` statement [kills the current script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) returning to an includer script (if any), but does not send any value to the output (that's the purpose of `die`/`exit`). You should:

1. Change the `return` to `echo`.
2. Remember to have a `header('Content-type: application/json')` sent if you intend to send json data, before any actual `echo` instruction or non-php content.
3. Remember to encode the data: `return json_encode($row)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the return statement but that was not the only thing wrong with my code. I was calling the $http.get('url',obj) when the correct way is $http.get('url'); I did it that way because I was trying to send an object to match results with on the backend side.

Comment: I thought such object had the intention to represent connection parameters.

Answer (score 4):

in your php make sure you echo your result the echoed results get passed into your variable

for example if you are passing in a varibale say from your scope

```
function($scope,$http){

$scope.obj= "your variable";

$reuslt = http.get('yourlocation/yourfile.php?val='+obj');
```

your php script

```
<?
$value = $_GET['val']


//not your variables have been passed in and you can use it to do your custom function wich ever way you like
and echo your result after wards
?>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call relative paths like that. The file has to exist at the public directory or lower. For instance, if all of your files are in /home/yourname/public, you'd need to call `/php-bin/example.php` instead, where php-bin is inside of the public directory (/home/yourname/public/php-bin).

Comment: The PHP file works and gets executed, and I know this because I do the same thing when I insert into a table in my DB.

Comment: I see that you said you figured out your issue.And just to make sure, you're saying you call it using `../php-bin/example.php`?

Comment: Yes because my structure is the following.

www/
   -js
   -css
   -php-bin
   -project/ file calls ../php-bin/file.php here